# suggestions on how i can resolve this "Semantic Issue" error

Tags: ios, xcode, error-handling, xcode4, iad

i have been trying to implement iAD into one of my view controllers and after writing the code for both the .h and .m file.... i get this semantic issue error:

```
@synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC mode
```

i specifically get this error right next to the @implementation of the .m file. any suggestions on how i can resolve this are much appreciated.

**ALSO** i was wondering whether it is ok to copy and paste this adbanner(Once its working) from this viewcontroller onto other view controllers withot re-coding ?

**This is my code for iAD within the .h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ADBannerView *banner;

@end
```

**This is my code for iAD within the .m file**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.banner.delegate = self;
}

- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
if (self.banner.bannerLoaded) {
    CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;
    CGRect bannerFrame = self.banner.frame;
    contentFrame.size.height -= self.banner.frame.size.height;
    bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    self.banner.frame = bannerFrame;
}
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:    (BOOL)willLeave
{
NSLog(@"bannerViewActionShouldBegin");
return YES;
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
NSLog(@"bannerViewDidLoadAd");
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"didFailToReceiveAdWithError");
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner {
NSLog(@"bannerViewActionDidFinish");
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you tried to enable ARC? `weak` can only be used with ARC (there is no garbage collection on iOS)

Comment: @Matthias Bauch yes, this is gonna sound silly but how do i do that ? and please explain your quote

Comment: There is a "Convert to Objective-C ARC" menu item in the Edit -> Refactor menu of Xcode. But before doing this you should educate yourself about ARC, this might cause problems with your existing code. If you like to stick with the manual release model replace `weak` with `assign`.

Comment: Or you can use `assign` instead of `weak`.

Comment: @MATTHIAS BAUCH ok i actually just had a quick read through automatic reference counting (ARC) before reading your reply so i understand that... however if i stick to manual release model  and replace weak with assign... i get a signal SIGABRT

Comment: Converting it to ARC gives me a build failed and simply changing it from weak to assign runs the build fine but then gives me a "signal SIGABRT"      int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: Before you attempt to convert to ARC, **back up your project**.

Comment: @HotLicks i wish i read that before doing so and however ive gone through with it but i keep getting that "Signal SIGABRT error"

Comment: Have you set the exception breakpoint?

Comment: @Hotlicks i have set the exception breakpoint but i still get the error... i set it to throw, no action selected but i still get the same error

Comment: The point is that the exception breakpoint should allow you to inspect the stack and perhaps tell where the error is coming from.

Comment: @HotLicks it give me a highlight in green within the breakpoint view of  main () line 15. does that mean its in the .m file line 15 counting from the import and also counting the gaps ?

Comment: It will generally highlight the line where the error occurs.  But it's important to look at the call stack display and see if there are any of your methods in the stack that will give you a clue as to the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enable ARC by going to Edit pressing Refactor and Convert to Objective-C ARC.